# Arrayformula + Vlookup + Date range , how?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to vlookup the rate defined for daterange per client. I got it working with date range only, or with client only, but I wasn't able to combine the two criteria. So I'd like to have a formula in I2 that would fill the I2:I range with valid rates.
Any idea how to solve this?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PwZDZ9JekNaJ-XIXmYeO_4Hu25ngqVEwDVFjF3fJDpw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(IFNA(VLOOKUP(G2:G, SORT(A2:A), 1, 1))&H2:H, {A2:A&C2:C, D2:D}, 2, 0)))
```

[image]